Searching through the content of a Cloudpage
I tried different methods including escape characters but I cannot search in Cloudpages for a certain word.
POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query

    {
        "page":
        {
            "page":1,
            "pageSize":50
        },
    
        "query":
        {
            "leftOperand":
            {
                "property":"content",
                "simpleOperator":"contains",
                "value": "AUtomationName_SqlName"
            },
            "logicalOperator":"AND",
            "rightOperand":
            {
                "property":"assetType.name",
                "simpleOperator":"equal",
                "value":"webpage"
            }
        },
    
        "sort":
        [
            { "property":"id", "direction":"ASC" }
        ],
    
        "fields":
        [
            "name",
            "content"
        ]
    }

I either get no result or many results that do not include the one I am searching for while there must be only one result, the one I don't get :)
Other alternatives I used:
"value": "%AUtomationName_SqlName%"
"value": "%"AUtomationName_SqlName"%" - StackExchange also escapes characters it seems, but this actually has %\ at the beginning and \ "% at the end.
I also tried it with "like" and "mustcontain", still no hope. :/
Funny part is it works well with the beginning of the Cloudpage HTML. Somehow, search functionality breaks whenever escape characters appear in the content string.

Finding a similar issue to what you describing, I resorted to recursively looping and searching through the content fields (in Python) and only relying on the query operators to traverse folder by folder.  A Content Builder search was my first step real Python-land -- like what emails contain CloudPagesURL(123), etc.

I was so eager to filter on the request part, not after I get the response but thanks a lot for the answer Adam. It seems like that is the only option.
